# Problem with MikTex and Hebrew when using 12pt font

Tags: fonts, miktex, fontsize, hebrew

I'm using MikTex 2.9 (on Windows 7), together with the culmus-latex pack (I used the instructions I found here: http://www.ma.huji.ac.il/~sameti/tex/culmusmiktex.html).
When working with the default (10pt I believe) font, or simply not specifying the font, everything works alright. But when choosing 12pt (with `\documentclass[hebrew,12pt]{article}`) the fonts **(only the Hebrew ones)** get all weird and their spacing goes wrong. Here's an example of what happens:
[image: bad spacing (12pt)]

as opposed to the normal result I get when I use 10pt:
[image: good spacing (10pt)]

I really need the 12pt font. Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Many thanks!

**Also** I'd like to point out that this only happens when exporting to PDF, if I just use LaTeX the DVI looks fine. But I usually need the PDF files.

**Edit:** Here is an example code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage[english,hebrew]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\linespread{1.3}
\begin{document}
\section{קיום הפוטנציאל המרוכב}
ראשית, נתאר מערכת דו-ממדית באמצעות משתנים מרוכבים: 
עבור שדה וקטורים שטוח )דו-ממדי(, נתאר כל אחת מהנקודות כנקודה במישור המרוכב, 
וכל פונקציה וקטורית תתואר כפונקציה מרוכבת. 
כמקובל, הרכיב האופקי יהווה את החלק הממשי והרכיב האנכי יהווה את החלק המדומה. 
נציג את שדה המהירות של נוזל זורם באמצעות פונקציה 
$f(z)$, 
באופן הבא:
\[ f(z) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y) \]
בשלב זה נציג הנחות על שדה הווקטורים. 
ההנחות שננסח אינן תקפות תמיד במציאות, אולם הן מהוות קירוב טוב לתנאים מציאותיים, 
וכן הן מאפשרות כוח חישובי שלא היה מתאפשר בלעדיהן.
\end{document}
```

And I put the .tex, .pdf and .log files here: http://www.sendspace.com/file/imx3qr

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Also, I admit complete ignorance of Hebrew but could you point out the difference between the two images you posted? Whatever is wrong, it apparently needs a trained eye to see it without some guidance!

Comment: What format are the fonts in? Since you are using XeLaTeX, you might be better off downloading the truetype or opentype fonts and using `fontspec`. I don't know how XeTeX-aware the package you are using is. (I don't actually really know the package since you've not posted code.)

Comment: the code is pretty simple, it even happens with something as simple as: '\begin{document}
בדיקה בעברית
\end{document}'

Comment: Also, I see why the problem isn't very clear when you look at one sentence of a foreign language, but if you zoom up you'll see the differences clearly. When Looking at an entire paragraph it gets really clear.

Comment: The code may be simple for you but it isn't easy to reproduce if one is not familiar with Hebrew. I couldn't just retype the lines based on the images you posted, even if I knew which class and packages you are loading. So you run the risk that only somebody who knows how to type Hebrew can investigate the problem.

Comment: I understand, so I added a detailed example in the original post which I hope makes it clearer.

Comment: I could not compile your code. Adding the line `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}` before the babel (as I often use in my hebrew documents) made it compile on my machine. Also, I did not get any font change that I could see between the default and 12pt...

Answer (score 1):

Installing the zipped file from the above website, running `updmap` and then using the example file `culmus-ex` with only loading the package without optional arguments gives for `10pt`:

[image]

and for `12pt`

[image]

Comment: Your picture looks just fine, this is what I'm supposed to get - do you have any idea what might be wrong with my system? @Herbert

Comment: I suppose a bad map file. I am a Linux user and installed all "by hand" without any problem. Try to update in MiKTeX the file name database and then update the font map. What do you get when running the example file?

Comment: I added a screenshot of my output of the example file with 12pt. Notice the differences especially in the fourth line (you can see it clearly in the first word actually) - the spaces are just wrong. I don't really know anything about map files and how to update the database... could you please explain?

Comment: @Omri16: Well I don't see it clearly. Instead of showing screenshots you should better make the complete code, the resulting pdfs and the log-files avalaible. Btw: Imho the culmus installation doesn't work without change in a current miktex. the hebrew.ldf is in the wrong folder and so not found before the standard hebrew.ldf.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer - I added the code, .pdf and .log files link in the original post. How can I fix the hebrew.ldf issue?